# Is it possible to check a set for a partial string in Python?

Tags: python

Say that I have a set of strings. Is it possible to search using a partial string, and if any of the values in the set contain that partial string, return the full string?

example:

```
thisSet = { 'orange', 'orabolo', 'apple', 'dog'}
partialString = 'ora'

setFunction(thisSet, partialString) 

> 'orange', 'orabolo'
```

Comment: `r = [e for e in thisSet if partialString in e]`

Comment: It's not clear, but if you mean "starts with ora", then a trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a better data structure if you need fast lookups. However, without profiling, that counts as premature optimization.

Comment: Well, yes. Iterate through the set and check each element for a partial match. Of course, that is not efficient, and gives you linear time complexity instead of constant time, sort of defeating the purpose of a `set` in the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple set comprehension:

```
{i for i in thisSet if partialString in i}
```

---

```
>>> thisSet = {'orange', 'orabolo', 'apple', 'dog'}
>>> partialString = 'ora'
>>> {i for i in thisSet if partialString in i}
{'orange', 'orabolo'}
>>>
```

Comment: 1. Why a set comprehension? 2. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores_style` 3. Isn't naming the variable `i` a bit confusing, since names like `i`, `j`, etc. are mostly used for counters?

Comment: @AMC: 1. Why not? You could use a loop, of course, but the same argument could be made about every comprehension (list, dict...). 2. I used the same variable names as the OP. 3. Yes, I agree, but I was not prioritizing convention while writing this answer.